# Chrome 121 enable-web-bluetooth-new-permissions-backend flag and BluetoothDevice.watchAdvertisements() disappeared

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, bluetooth, web-bluetooth

I have a web app using the Web Bluetooth API. Today it suddenly stops working, so I checked chrome://flags and found out `#enable-web-bluetooth-new-permissions-backend` no longer exists. I also checked [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BluetoothDevice) and found that `BluetoothDevice.watchAdvertisements()` (The API I am using) is being red underlined. What's happened to the API? Is there any new API to do the same thing?

Comment: MDN doesn't document all of Chromes little experiments - try reading the Chrome documentation ... oh ... yeah - you will note that MDN marks it as experimental and likely to change ... perhaps the change is, it's gone

Comment: I did a search for you - was easy to find information about this - https://chromestatus.com/feature/5180688812736512

Comment: By the way, if you have a public facing Web App that uses *experimental* features ... well, now you know why you should never include such trinkets in public apps :p

Comment: Thanks. So it looks like I have to migrate to requestLEScan. I know using experimental features is not good, but that's the only option anyway. :(

Comment: Wait I don't see requestLEScan available on my browser either.

Comment: Wouldn't be the first time googol turned off a replaced feature before the replacement was implemented - have you tried Edge? Microsoft seems to be a little less heavy handed than googol

Comment: I looked it up and found that requestLEScan is hiding behind a different experimental flags (enable-experimental-web-platform-features). Thanks for helping a lot :)

Comment: @JaromandaX That's all well and good, but when there are literally zero other options, you have to do what you have to do.  And then for Chrome to just remove them without a replacement up and running, is very poor.

Answer (score 2):

In an effort to keep us from having experimental code hanging around forever the ability to set a flag in chrome://flags usually has an expiration date. There's an "unexpire flags" flag you can turn on to keep it for an extra version.

We get a notification when a flag is about to expire but since the team is busy (the reason we haven't gotten to making this feature enabled by default) sometimes it gets missed.

Comment: But what happens when the flag is straight up removed?
As per the chrome://flags page, it states:

"Temporarily unexpire flags that expired as of M119/M120. These flags will be removed soon."

Once removed, I presume the ability to 'unexpire' them becomes null and void?

Comment: That is correct, however the intention is not for these flags to be removed and their expiration was extended in https://issues.chromium.org/issues/41496099. In M122 you will see the flag is no longer expired.

Comment: @ReillyGrant Is the flag likely to be enabled by default any time soon? It would improve our product if this feature were available to normal users (who I cannot ask to set flags) because my web app could then automatically reconnect to paired devices as they came back into range.